# How to perform AssertJ recursive comparison with strict type checking only on collection elements?

Tags: java, kotlin, testing, junit, assertj

I would like to compare two collections using AssertJ with strict type checking. However, I only care about the strict types of collection elements not the collection itself.

For instace in the case below I would like assertion
`assertThat(listOfA).usingRecursiveComparison().withStrictTypeChecking().isEqualTo(arrayListOfA)` to be true while now it's false because listOfA is of type `SingletonList` and arrayListOfA is of type `ArrayList`

```
@Test
fun `test`() {
    val listOfA = listOf(TestClassA("Name"))
    val arrayListOfA = arrayListOf(TestClassA("Name"))
    val arrayListOfB = arrayListOf(TestClassB("Name"))
    assertThat(listOfA).usingRecursiveComparison().isEqualTo(arrayListOfA)
    assertThat(listOfA).usingRecursiveComparison().isEqualTo(arrayListOfB)
    assertThat(listOfA).usingRecursiveComparison().withStrictTypeChecking().isEqualTo(arrayListOfA)
    assertThat(listOfA).usingRecursiveComparison().withStrictTypeChecking().isNotEqualTo(arrayListOfB)
}

class TestClassA(val name: String)

class TestClassB(val name: String)
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: So just disable `withStrictTypeChecking`?

Comment: @Jorn the OP stated that strict type checking should still be performed on the collection elements. Removing `withStrictTypeChecking` does not enforce strict type checking for the elements.

Comment: I don't see the point. You can't just compare those using `equals`?

Comment: The element types might not implement `equals`, hence the usefulness of the recursive comparison.

Comment: The code above is just an example. Let's say that I simply don't know the types of the collections for neither actual nor expected but I want to assert on their contents.

Answer (score 2):

Your target could be achieved with standard list assertions and a [`RecursiveComparator`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/recursive/comparison/RecursiveComparator.html):

```
val listOfA = listOf(TestClassA("Name"))
val arrayListOfB = arrayListOf(TestClassB("Name"))

val configuration = RecursiveComparisonConfiguration()

configuration.strictTypeChecking(false) // default

assertThat(listOfA)
    .usingElementComparator(RecursiveComparator(configuration))
    .isEqualTo(arrayListOfB) // succeeds

configuration.strictTypeChecking(true)

assertThat(listOfA)
    .usingElementComparator(RecursiveComparator(configuration))
    .isEqualTo(arrayListOfB) // fails
```

Not as fluent as one would expect but it's the best option I see at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The response proposed by Stefano works for the given example. However, with more complex types inside the array it was failing. I am not 100% sure why but it seemed like ignoring collection order did not work.

In the end I was able to achieve my goal with a custom condition:

```
    private fun iterablesEqualCondition(recursiveComparisonConfiguration: RecursiveComparisonConfiguration, other: Iterable<*>): Condition<Any> {
        fun condition(actual: Any): Boolean {
            assertThat((actual as Iterable<*>).toList()).usingRecursiveComparison(recursiveComparisonConfiguration).isEqualTo(other.toList())
            return true
        }
        return Condition(::condition, "Iterables are equal condition")
    }

assertThat(listOfA).satisfies(iterablesEqualCondition(RecursiveComparisonConfiguration.builder()
            .withStrictTypeChecking(true)
            .withIgnoreCollectionOrder(true).build(), arrayListOfA))
```

Comment: If you could share a more complex example at https://github.com/assertj/assertj/issues/new, we'd be happy to look at it.